# Send data in body to API in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating a web API application using ASP.NET Core 2.0.

I have created the API for a project but while trying to call the API which is a `[HttpPost]` method through the Restlet client, I am not getting any value in `model` even after passing the data in `Body`. I have also used `[FromBody]`, but still no result.

Sample code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]Login model)
{
    try
    {
        return SuccessResponse(SuccessConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESSFULLY);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ErrorResponse(ErrorConstants.API_INTERNAL_ERROR);
    }
}
```

All the APIs which do not have any parameter are working fine. But in this case, I am getting `model` as `null` even after passing in values from the Restlet client.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: What is `Login` class? What exactly you are passing?

Comment: Show the json being send

Comment: Login is a model and in this I am passing the following in the body

{
  "Email":"bimal.kumar@zibtek.com"
  "Password":"Tudip@123"
}

Comment: How is your class Login? What is your route? Put more information.

Comment: [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AccountController : BaseController
    {
        #region stubs

        [HttpPost("login")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]Login model)
        {
            try
            {
                return SuccessResponse(SuccessConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESSFULLY);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ErrorResponse(ErrorConstants.API_INTERNAL_ERROR);
            }
        }
 }